# Optimise Oracle Join query (multiple joins on the same table)

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have three tables in my Oracle database:

**Table 1:** Contains employees and phone numbers from Company A:

```
EmployeeName, WorkPhone, MobilePhone, PersonalPhone,OtherPhone
Adam,1234,1111,0987,NULL
Catherine,2345,5432,NULL,NULL
Tom, 4567,7654,0101,0002
```

**Table 2:** Contains employees and phone numbers from Company B:

```
EmployeeName, WorkPhone, MobilePhone, PersonalPhone, OtherPhone
David,8888,9999,0000,1245
Sam,4321,5432,NULL,NULL
Clara,4567,7654,0101,NULL
```

**Table 3:** Contains phone numbers where the phone number could either be recorded in Column 1 or in Column 2 or in both:

```
PhoneNumber1, PhoneNumber2
1234,NULL
7654,7575
0000,1111
1234,4321
NULL,1234
5432,1234
```

Now, I would like to join phone numbers in **Table 3** to their respective employees as well as to know where that employee works (Company A or B). The challenge is that we have a total of 8 "matching" possibilities for **Table 2** and 8 for **Table 2** (Each column in Table A/B can join to either column 1 or column2 in **Table 3**.

The datasets are big. (20M rows in table 1 and about 2M rows in table 2).Let's leave out Table2 for now and concentrate on joining Table1 to Table3 only.

If I do the following, the query is very very slow (and I imagine it would run out of temp table space at some point):

```
SELECT * FROM Table3 t3
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
ON (PhoneNumber1 in (WorkPhone, MobilePhone, PersonalPhone, OtherPhone)
   OR PhoneNumber2 in (WorkPhone, MobilePhone, PersonalPhone, OtherPhone))
```

If I do the following, the query runs out of temp table space (and i am not allowed to increase that)

```
SELECT * FROM Table3
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1_1
PhoneNumber1 = t1_1.WorkPhone
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1_2
PhoneNumber1 = t1_1.MobilePhone
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1_3
PhoneNumber1 = t1_1.PersonalPhone
...etc
```

How could we optimise this query?

Comment: What output are you looking for, for the sample data? Your first query gets all columns from both tables; the second gets all columns from all projections across the multiple instances of table1, which probably isn't what you want. Which columns (from either table) do you actually need to retrieve, and what do you expect to see if two numbers for one contact match?

Comment: What does the query explain plan show you? Start there when looking for optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unpivot either or both tables so you get a row for each (not-null) phone number, and then do a simple join:

```
with cte1 as (
  select * from (
    select 'A' as company, t.* from table1 t
    union all
    select 'B' as company, t.* from table2 t
  )
  unpivot (phone for type in (workphone as 'Work', mobilephone as 'Mobile',
    personalphone as 'Personal', otherphone as 'Other'))
),
cte2 as (
  select distinct phone from table3
  unpivot (phone for type in (phonenumber1 as 'Phone1', phonenumber2 as 'Phone2'))
)
select cte1.*
from cte2
join cte1 on cte1.phone = cte2.phone;

C EMPLOYEEN TYPE     PHON
- --------- -------- ----
A Adam      Work     1234
A Adam      Mobile   1111
A Catherine Mobile   5432
A Tom       Mobile   7654
B David     Personal 0000
B Sam       Work     4321
B Sam       Mobile   5432
B Clara     Mobile   7654

8 rows selected.
```

The first CTE first unions tables 1 and 2 together, while adding a pseudocolumn indicating which table the data came from; and then unpivots the result so you get one row per phone number per person:

```
...
select * from cte1;

C EMPLOYEEN TYPE     PHON
- --------- -------- ----
A Adam      Work     1234
A Adam      Mobile   1111
A Adam      Personal 0987
A Catherine Work     2345
A Catherine Mobile   5432
...
B Clara     Personal 0101

18 rows selected.
```

You could also unpivot each table first and then union those together, might be worth trying both ways.

The second CTE unpivots table 3 so you get one row for each not-null phone number in either column:

```
...
select * from cte2;

PHON
----
7654
7575
0000
4321
1234
5432
1111

7 rows selected.
```

Of course, this is on a tiny amount of dummy data; it might perform even worse on your actual larger tables... And I've made some assumptions about what you want to end up with.

Another approach might be to just convert the table 3 values into a single column which you can do manually instead of explicitly unpivoting, and then unioning together multiple queries against eachof the first two tables:

```
with cte as (
  select phone from (
    select phonenumber1 as phone from table3
    union
    select phonenumber2 as phone from table3
  )
  where phone is not null
)
select 'A' as customer, employeename, 'Work' as type, workphone as phone
from table1 where workphone in (select phone from cte)
union all
select 'A', employeename, 'Mobile', mobilephone
from table1 where mobilephone in (select phone from cte)
union all
select 'A', employeename, 'Personal', mobilephone
from table1 where personalphone in (select phone from cte)
union all
select 'A', employeename, 'Other', mobilephone
from table1 where otherphone in (select phone from cte)
union all 
select 'B', employeename, 'Work', workphone
from table2 where workphone in (select phone from cte)
union all
select 'B', employeename, 'Mobile', mobilephone
from table2 where mobilephone in (select phone from cte)
union all
select 'B', employeename, 'Personal', personalphone
from table2 where personalphone in (select phone from cte)
union all
select 'B', employeename, 'Other', otherphone
from table2 where otherphone in (select phone from cte)
/

C EMPLOYEEN TYPE     PHON
- --------- -------- ----
A Adam      Work     1234
A Adam      Mobile   1111
A Catherine Mobile   5432
A Tom       Mobile   7654
B Sam       Work     4321
B Sam       Mobile   5432
B Clara     Mobile   7654
B David     Personal 0000

8 rows selected.
```

Which I personally find harder to read and maintain, but it may perform significantly differently too.

Comment: Magic. Unpivoting increases the speed of the query by a lot. Thanks!